# Creating environment variables for systemd and spawned processes (bash)

Tags: environment-variables, systemd

I would like to find a **single** place where I can set an environment variable that will be used for both systemd scripts and bash scripts. I've been 50% successful. I can add systemd-visible environment variable to /etc/systemd/system.conf as:

```
DefaultEnvironment=APPLICATION=user1 ID=1
```

and then use it in a systemd service script:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin $APPLICATION --noclear %I 38400 linux
```

This works. However, I would like the same environment variables to then be visible to the bash environment started by this getty. I have tried several variations of:

```
[Service]
Environment=$APPLICATION
PassEnvironment=APPLICATION ID
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin $APPLICATION --noclear %I 38400 linux
```

with and without the "Environment" declaration, etc. ad nauseum but a subsequent

```
echo $APPLICATION
```

in the spawned shell shows it is unset.

I know that I can set the environment variable again in /etc/bashrc but, again, I would like to be able to set this only **one** place and have it be useable to both systemd and bash (I need to make this a bit idiot proof).

What am I missing here??

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. My best solution so far is to set the system environment using system-environment-generators. Any system process started by systemd will get this environment. But now the sad news. I'm struggling with agetty too, because `/bin/login` seems to discard the environment variables. I found a workaround for ssh though.